# Adding a column to pandas dataframe based on bool values in existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which I would like to add a new column to. The new column values will be determined by an existing column in the dataframe which contains bools. The code below is my C++ logic applied in python but I would like a more 'pythonic' way to do this. `'isfixed'` contains the bools and the new column will be `'color code'`

```
for i in range(data_2015['isfixed'].count()):
     if data_2015['isfixed'][i] == True:
         data_2015['color code'][i] = 'Blue'
     else:
         data_2015['color code'][i] = 'Green'
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I would say this approach is perfectly pythonic but not very pandonic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
data_2015['color_code'] = np.where(data_2015['isfixed'], 'Blue', 'Green')
```

A demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'isfixed': [True, False, True]})

df
Out: 
  isfixed
0    True
1   False
2    True


df['color_code'] = np.where(df['isfixed'], 'Blue', 'Green')

df
Out: 
  isfixed color_code
0    True       Blue
1   False      Green
2    True       Blue
```

Comment: Thanks @ayhan. I like this, just one line. The pythonic way rules!

Comment: You are welcome. Just a note: this can also be done by `df['color_code'] = ['Blue' if row else 'Green' for row in df['isfixed']]` but built-in numpy/pandas functions are generally much faster than iterating over a Series/array.

Comment: Right, I have been warned about iterating over series with respect to speed. My understanding is that it is fastest to apply functions over the entire series rather than iterate through each element, right?

Comment: Exactly. Here's a more detailed explanation since you mentioned C: ([data types](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/02.01-Understanding-Data-Types.ipynb) and [ufuncs](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/02.03-Computation-on-arrays-ufuncs.ipynb))

Answer (score 0):

For a pure Pandas solution:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'isfixed': [True, False, True]})`

`df['color_code'] = ["Blue" if value==True else "Green" for value in df['isfixed']]`